# How to make procedural Powder Coat material?

Tags: materials, procedural

i am Industrial designer and i need a powder coated material, im trying to make it procedural but i cant achieve a realistic solution.
Has anyone had any experience with trying to make a material like this?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably accomplish this pretty easily with a Noise Texture. I just scaled it to 60 and upped the detail and roughness a bit. I mixed it with white before running through a Bump Node to make the effect less jarring, and mixed the main color with an Ambient Occlusion Node to highlight the dimples. I also increased the metallic value to try and make it match the image you posted. Don't forget to enable Ambient Occlusion in the render properties panel:

[image: NoiseMetal]