# Create white powder coat material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

does anyone here created some material that looks like this using Cycles?
[image: white powder coat]
I was able to create a material that looks similar using Eevee, but its looking completely different using Cycles.

For Eevee I used [How to make procedural Powder Coat material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/211478/how-to-make-procedural-powder-coat-material)

Comment: I remade the material you linked, and for me it looked identical in both eevee and cycles.

Comment: Hello :). Keep in mind that Eevee's Material preview uses HDRI to light the scene, while Cycles Render Preview uses solid grey by default.